# My WPF program is not displaying GUI elements

Tags: c#, wpf, mahapps.metro

I have a loading screen which gets shown from within my program to prevent my program from seeming unresponsive whilst it loads, however when I use `loadingScreen.Show();` and `this.Hide();`, the loading screen window shows fine, however none of the GUI elements from MahApps.Metro appear, nor does the label.

Here is the code that I have so far:

```
LoadingScreen screen = new LoadingScreen();
screen.InitializeComponent();
this.Hide();
screen.Show();
```

and then the things that need to be loaded, and finally

```
screen.Hide();
this.Show();
```

Comment: Why not use some existing busy indicators?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have a threading issue.  Your splash screen is locking the main thread and it never gets to your main application.  Here is how I have solved this issue.  I created a new thread for the splash screen and initialization.  I used a ManualResetEvent to signal back to the main thread when initialization is complete and the main application can proceed.

```
public partial class App : Application
{
    private static LoadingScreen splashScreen;
    private static ManualResetEvent resetSplash;

    [STAThread]
    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            resetSplash = new ManualResetEvent(false);
            var splashThread = new Thread(ShowSplash);
            splashThread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
            splashThread.IsBackground = true;
            splashThread.Name = "My Splash Screen";
            splashThread.Start();
            resetSplash.WaitOne(); //wait here until init is complete

            //Now your initialization is complete so go ahead and show your main screen
            var app = new App();
            app.InitializeComponent();
            app.Run();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //Log it or something else
            throw;
        }
    }

    private static void ShowSplash()
    {
        splashScreen = new LoadingScreen(); 
        splashScreen.Show();
        try
        {
            //this would be your async init code inside the task
            Task.Run(async () => await Initialization()) 
            .ContinueWith(t =>
                {
                    //log it
                }, TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnFaulted);
    }
    catch (AggregateException ex)
    {
        //log it
    }
    resetSplash.Set();
    Dispatcher.Run();
}
```

}

Comment: Sorry, forgot to mention; this should be called from a button click handler, so do I do something similar to this?

Comment: I would still do it the same way.  The difference being that instead of it being in Main you would do the rest the same on button Click.  Instead of ```var app = new App();``` you would put ```var window = new MyWindowClass();``` then ```window.Show();```